# How do I set up the encoding correctly in Diplodoc?

Tags: diplodoc

When compiling a project with Russian letters, they are displayed incorrectly. How can this be corrected?

I tried to add Russian localization to my project, but I got incorrect character display. I also tried adding the "ru" parameter to the .yfm settings.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the files in the docs folder to UTF-8.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as how to accomplish what you told ... specifically how you did it in your case.  Thanks